# Return only single occurrences of a string

Tags: python

I am trying to return only single occurrences of the characters in a list of strings. So the code below

```
words = ['man','map','human']
[letter for word in words for letter in word]
```

gives this output:

```
['m', 'a', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'p', 'h', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'n']
```

and when I use a `set()` method the output is exactly as I want it as seen below

```
words = ['man','map','human']
set([letter for word in words for letter in word ])
```

output:

```
{'a', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'u'}
```

But the instruction for the problem I am trying to solve requires that I do not use sets. Could someone help with an alternative way to get the desired output. I appreciate  your time.

Comment: you need to manually keep track of  any letter you have seen (since you cannot use sets)

Comment: I suggest stop trying to jump directly to comprehensions. Explode your algorithm and do it step at a time and see where you can make optimizations after you have solved the problem.

Comment: Can you use dictionaries?

Comment: @MikeMüller no dictionaries should not be used

Comment: See [**`unique_everseen`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: unique_everseen relies on sets I'm afraid

Comment: @Pedro, I clicked it in error, unfortunately, I don't think it  can be undone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator expression, you don't need to create the intermediate list of letters:

```
words = ['man','map','human']
res = []
for letter in (letter for word in words for letter in word):
    if letter not in res:
        res.append(letter)
```

Now:

```
>>> res
['m', 'a', 'n', 'p', 'h', 'u']
```

This is equivalent to a nested loop:

```
res = []
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in res:
            res.append(letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, not using `set` is not good idea but in case,

Try:

```
unique_list = []

words = ['man', 'map', 'human']

[unique_list.append(letter) for word in words for letter in word if letter not in unique_list]

print(unique_list)
```

It will output:

```
['m', 'a', 'n', 'p', 'h', 'u']
```

And if you want to sort, `unique_list.sort()` which will emit

```
['a', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'u']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['m', 'a', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'p', 'h', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'n']
withoutduplicates = [(list[i]) for i in range (0,len(list)) if list[i] not in list[:i]]
print withoutduplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without comprehension:

```
def nodupes(l):
    seen = []
    for c in l:
        if c not in seen:
            seen.append(c)
    return seen

nodupes(['m', 'a', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'p', 'h', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'n'])
```